# Is blood money a religious or cultural practice, and would it apply in Indonesia?

Tags: sharia, islamic-basis, culture, diyya

There've been a couple of tweets about "blood money" and Indonesia, to do with impending executions by the Indonesian government of two members of the [Bali Nine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bali_Nine):

From [Father Bob](https://twitter.com/FatherBob/status/567628746950057984)

> Allowance is made/encouraged in the Quran to substitute "blood money"
>   for "blood letting". Have we approached the Indonesian offended party?

From [Fiona Patten](https://twitter.com/FionaPattenMLC/status/567788417171353601)

> Will Indonesian govt accept blood money? I'm sure we can easily raise
>   $1.9m which seems to be the price for a life
>   [http://gu.com/p/45zyb/stwprice](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/feb/16/bali-nine-indonesia-has-death-penalty-double-standard-says-brother-of-spared-maid) …

Is "Blood Money" a religious practice, or is it a cultural practice? Also, is it applicable in parts of Indonesia outside of Aceh, or only applicable in middle eastern countries like Saudi Arabia?

Comment: I don't have time to do up a proper answer right now, but the concept you're looking for is called "Diyya" in Islamic jurisprudence (relevant Wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diyya)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment (by @goldPseudo),  this "blood money" is called "[Diyya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diyya)" in Islamic jurisprudence. In truth, this issue and even this word (Diyya) is available in the holy Qur'an as well:

> وَمَا كَانَ لِمُؤْمِنٍ أَن يَقْتُلَ مُؤْمِنًا إِلَّا خَطَأً ۚ وَمَن
>   قَتَلَ مُؤْمِنًا خَطَأً فَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ مُّؤْمِنَةٍ وَ**دِيَةٌ**
>   مُّسَلَّمَةٌ إِلَىٰ أَهْلِهِ إِلَّا أَن يَصَّدَّقُوا ۚ فَإِن كَانَ مِن
>   قَوْمٍ عَدُوٍّ لَّكُمْ وَهُوَ مُؤْمِنٌ فَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ
>   مُّؤْمِنَةٍ ۖ وَإِن كَانَ مِن قَوْمٍ بَيْنَكُمْ وَبَيْنَهُم مِّيثَاقٌ
>   فَدِيَةٌ مُّسَلَّمَةٌ إِلَىٰ أَهْلِهِ وَتَحْرِيرُ رَقَبَةٍ مُّؤْمِنَةٍ
>   ۖ فَمَن لَّمْ يَجِدْ فَصِيَامُ شَهْرَيْنِ مُتَتَابِعَيْنِ تَوْبَةً
>   مِّنَ اللَّـهِ ۗ وَكَانَ اللَّـهُ عَلِيمًا حَكِيمًا ﴿٩٢﴾
>
> And never is it for a believer to kill a believer except by mistake.
>   And whoever kills a believer by mistake - then the freeing of a
>   believing slave and a **compensation payment [lit: *diyya*]** presented to the deceased's
>   family [is required] unless they give [up their right as] charity. But
>   if the deceased was from a people at war with you and he was a
>   believer - then [only] the freeing of a believing slave; and if he was
>   from a people with whom you have a treaty - then a compensation
>   payment presented to his family and the freeing of a believing slave.
>   And whoever does not find [one or cannot afford to buy one] - then
>   [instead], a fast for two months consecutively, [seeking] acceptance
>   of repentance from Allah. And Allah is ever Knowing and Wise.
>
> <sup>[[An-Nisa 92](http://quran.com/4/92)]</sup>

Furthermore, there are several traditions (hadiths) regarding Diyya in addition to the holy Qur'an.

---

Source(s):

- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/4:92)
- [feghhy.blogsky.com](http://feghhy.blogsky.com/1383/12/23/post-17/)

Comment: Well done @goldPseudo, you did a nice edition, hopefully I'd learn some points from it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Blood money is both cultural and religious practice. It is cultural first which was adopted in Islam. [This verse 2:178](http://quran.com/2/178), although cannot be *cleanly* translated says

> But if the killer is forgiven by the brother (or the relatives, etc.)
>   of the killed against blood money, then adhering to it with fairness
>   and payment of the blood money, to the heir should be made in
>   fairness. This is an alleviation and a mercy from your Lord.So after this whoever transgresses the limits (i.e. **kills the killer after taking the blood money**), **he shall have a painful torment**.[Mohsin Khan]

**Would it be applicable in Indonesia?**

Yes. Because there is no distinctions made in Islam based on people or region. Islamic laws is practice everywhere in the same way. But since it was really a cultural thing in Arabia, this law is strictly practiced only in Arabia. In other parts, it did not get wide recognition. But nevertheless, it is applicable in Indonesia.